# csvreader does not show anything

Tags: csvsimple, babel-french

I'm trying to use for the first time the package csvsimple. It worked fine with my .csv file and the command `\csvautobooktabular` but I'm not able to use it with `\csvreader`. Here is a MWE. Could someone show me where my code could be wrong?
(I'm using Overleaf to compile this code)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[legacy]{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
Echant.;Masse;Inc.;Volume;Inc.;Masse vol.;Inc.
;;masse;;volume;;masse vol.
[-];[g];[g];[ml];[ml];[kg/m3];[kg/m3]
Paul;23.4;0.1;7.52;0.01;3.11;0.02
1;43.5;0.1;13.9;0.1;3.13;0.03
3B;5.0;0.1;1.7;0.2;3.0;0.4
H12bc;4.7;0.1;1.6;0.2;2.9;0.4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\shorthandoff{;}
\csvautobooktabular[separator=semicolon]{data2.csv}
\shorthandon{;}
\captionof{table}{Exemple 1.}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\shorthandoff{;}
\csvreader[ separator=semicolon,
            tabular=@{}ccccccc@{},
            table head=\toprule
            a & b & c & d & e & f & g \\ \midrule,
            table foot=\bottomrule
          ]
    {data2.csv}{}{}
\shorthandon{;}
\captionof{table}{Exemple 2.}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have no typesetting instruction in the last argument, try e.g. with `\csvlinetotablerow`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `csvreader` how to typeset the tabular exactly, for example like this (which would be a very explicit way):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[legacy]{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
Echant.;Masse;Inc.;Volume;Inc.;Masse vol.;Inc.
;;masse;;volume;;masse vol.
[-];[g];[g];[ml];[ml];[kg/m3];[kg/m3]
Paul;23.4;0.1;7.52;0.01;3.11;0.02
1;43.5;0.1;13.9;0.1;3.13;0.03
3B;5.0;0.1;1.7;0.2;3.0;0.4
H12bc;4.7;0.1;1.6;0.2;2.9;0.4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\shorthandoff{;}
\csvreader[ 
    separator=semicolon,
    tabular={ @{} *{8}{c} @{} },
    table head=\toprule
    Echant. & Masse & Inc. & Volume & Inc. & Masse vol. & Inc. \\ \midrule,
    table foot=\bottomrule
  ]
{data2.csv}{}{
    \csvcoli & 
    \csvcolii & 
    \csvcoliii & 
    \csvcoliv & 
    \csvcolv & 
    \csvcolvi &
    \csvcolvii  
}
\shorthandon{;}
\captionof{table}{Exemple 2.}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also just use `\csvlinetotablerow` instead, as suggested in the comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[legacy]{csvsimple}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
Echant.;Masse;Inc.;Volume;Inc.;Masse vol.;Inc.
;;masse;;volume;;masse vol.
[-];[g];[g];[ml];[ml];[kg/m3];[kg/m3]
Paul;23.4;0.1;7.52;0.01;3.11;0.02
1;43.5;0.1;13.9;0.1;3.13;0.03
3B;5.0;0.1;1.7;0.2;3.0;0.4
H12bc;4.7;0.1;1.6;0.2;2.9;0.4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\shorthandoff{;}
\csvreader[ 
    separator=semicolon,
    tabular={ @{} *{8}{c} @{} },
    table head=\toprule
    Echant. & Masse & Inc. & Volume & Inc. & Masse vol. & Inc. \\ \midrule,
    table foot=\bottomrule
  ]
{data2.csv}{}{
    \csvlinetotablerow  
}
\shorthandon{;}
\captionof{table}{Exemple 2.}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```